# How to compare the same properties of two different class objects in C#?

Tags: c#, nuget

I have two classes A and B which have some properties that are the same. I am looking for a way to compare only the same properties and was hoping if there was some **nuget** package that did this for any type of class.

I don't know how to go about looking for such a nuget package, I already tried using if statements to compare the same properties, but I have a lot of cases like this so it would be easier to use a nuget package to do it.

Also, **it is not possible to include inheritance here**, as the two classes are not logically linked.

```
class A {
  string title;
  DateTime publishDate;
  string Author;
  int numberOfSales;
}
class B {
  DateTime publishDate;
  int numberOfSales;
}
```

I have already did something like this to compare the two same properties

```
if (A.publishDate.Equals(B.publishDate)) {
  // Do something
}
if (A.numberOfSales == B.numberOfSales) {
  // Do something
}
```

I would really be grateful if someone could let me know if there is some **nuget** package that would just compare the same properties of the two classes.

Comment: What about having them both implement an interface?

Comment: Comparing same properties => assuming you want to compare property with same names. Assuming these are simple properties (i.e, not objects, only value types), you can use reflection to easily compare as many property as you want. If the properties are objects than it might be more tricky but still can be done. Dont think you should be adding a new library just for this.

Comment: I could see it done via `System.Reflection`.You get all `PropertyInfo` of both objects , you then compare them by name , type and when they match use `PropertyInfo.GetValue`.

Comment: Another option is to create an extension method for comparing two properties of the same type. This is not bound to any class type an can exist within your namespace.

Comment: @Stefan thanks I'll try the extension method. Where should I put the method as I have multiple projects in a solution and may have to use it many times?

Comment: @Sweeper the interface idea is also good, but then i would have to make a lot of interfaces, as there are lot of cases like the one I posted in the question

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD You can put the static extension class in a new project or in an existing "common" project and reference it in the projects you want to use it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like a more controlled way better where you just type the compaire properties as you did in your sample, perhaps use an [icomparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.8) interface.

he reflection option that is offered and will be offered is slow, could give null pointer exceptions etc but write once work always, it's not a nuget package but here you go.

```
public static List<PropertyInfo> GetDifferences(object test1, object test2)
{
    if (test1 is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(test1));
    if (test2 is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(test2));

    List<PropertyInfo> differences = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in test1.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (test2.GetType().GetProperties().Any(a => a.Name.Equals(property.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal)))
        {
            object value1 = property.GetValue(test1, null);
            object value2 = property.GetValue(test2, null);
            if ((value1 == null) || !value1.Equals(value2))
            {
                differences.Add(property);
            }
        }
    }
    return differences;
}
```

It will return the properties that both have and are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

Why you don't use native interface in c# ?

you can use Icomprable interface like this :

```
 public class A:IComparable<B>
        {
            public string title;
            public DateTime publishDate;
            public string Author;
            public int numberOfSales;
            public int CompareTo(B other)
            {
                if (this.numberOfSales == other.numberOfSales && this.publishDate.Equals(other.publishDate))
                    return 0;
                if (this.numberOfSales != other.numberOfSales && this.publishDate.Equals(other.publishDate))
                    return 1;
                if (this.numberOfSales == other.numberOfSales && !this.publishDate.Equals(other.publishDate))
                    return 2;
                return -1;
            }
        }
        public class B
        {
            public DateTime publishDate;
            public int numberOfSales;
        }
```

then you can use it like this :

```
  switch (aClass.CompareTo(bClass))
            {
                case 0:Console.WriteLine("both properties are equal");break;
                case 1:Console.WriteLine("PublishDate only equal"); break;
                case 2: Console.WriteLine("NumberOfSales only equal"); break;
                case -1: Console.WriteLine("None are equal"); break;
            }
```

I hope it will be useful

Comment: I'd feel weird putting more logic into the result of `CompareTo` than what it was intended for: negative means "this" is sorted *before* "other", zero means "this is sorted equally to "other" and positive means "this" is sorted *after* other. -- also, in this case, `IEquatable<B>` would probably make the intend of checking for equality more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Reflection.

For example, this class will all fields (because your sample class listings have no `Properties`, they only have `Fields`) and return a list of them:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

public static class Comparer {
        public static List<String> Compare<T1, T2>(T1 a, T2 b) {
            var result = new List<String>(); // you can choose to return FieldInfo or values or whatever...
            // you can also use .GetProperties() if you actually want Properties with getters.
            var aFields = typeof(T1).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            var bFields = typeof(T2).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

            var aCommonFields = new List<FieldInfo>();
            var bCommonFields = new List<FieldInfo>();

            Func<IEnumerable<FieldInfo>, FieldInfo, bool> predicate = (other, x) => other.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Name == x.Name && z.FieldType == x.FieldType) != null;

            aCommonFields.AddRange(aFields.Where(x => predicate(bFields, x)));

            bCommonFields.AddRange(bFields.Where(x => predicate(aCommonFields, x)));

            foreach(var aCommonField in aCommonFields) {
                var bCommonField = bCommonFields.First(bField => predicate(new[]{ aCommonField }, bField));
                var aValue = aCommonField.GetValue(a);
                var bValue = bCommonField.GetValue(b);
                if (aValue.Equals(bValue)) {
                    result.Add(aCommonField.Name);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Sample usage:

```
                var a1 = new A { numberOfSales = 42 };
                var b2 = new B { numberOfSales = 42 };
                var commons = Comparer.Compare(a1, b2);

                foreach(var common in commons) {
                    if (common == nameof(A.numberOfSales)) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Number of sales match!");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Reflexion is a big hammer, the most elegant way and the most performance (IMO without testing) will be the implementation of the IComparable as @masoud said.